# Alpine with AMQP php extension

Tags: dockerfile, alpine-linux

How should Dockerfile look with Alpine (`alpine:3.10`) for using rabbit and rabbit dependency packages? 
I have an Ubuntu configuration. How to reproduce it for Alpine ?

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        git \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        librabbitmq-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libonig-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
        pdo_mysql \
        zip \
    && pecl install amqp \
    && docker-php-ext-enable amqp # Enable the Extension

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
COPY project/ /var/www/project
WORKDIR /var/www/project/
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to install those librairies `rabbitmq-c` & `rabbitmq-c-dev`.

So you can do:

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        git \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        rabbitmq-c rabbitmq-c-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libonig-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
        pdo_mysql \
        zip \
    && pecl install amqp \
    && docker-php-ext-enable amqp # Enable the Extension

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
COPY project/ /var/www/project
WORKDIR /var/www/project/
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me on php:7.4-fpm-alpine3.12

```
RUN apk --update --no-cache add build-base \
        autoconf \
        rabbitmq-c-dev
    
RUN pecl install amqp
RUN docker-php-ext-enable amqp
```

Answer (score 2):

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

# Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Extensions
RUN echo "Extensions install - start" \
    # Sockets
    && docker-php-ext-install sockets \
    # Amqp
    && apk add --no-cache --update rabbitmq-c-dev \
    && apk add --no-cache --update --virtual .phpize-deps $PHPIZE_DEPS \
    && pecl install -o -f amqp \
    && docker-php-ext-enable amqp \
    && apk del .phpize-deps \
    #
    && echo "Extensions install - finish"
```

Answer (score 1):

For `php:8.0.6-fpm-alpine` I solved this using:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache rabbitmq-c-dev && \
    mkdir -p /usr/src/php/ext/amqp && \
    curl -fsSL https://pecl.php.net/get/amqp | tar xvz -C "/usr/src/php/ext/amqp" --strip 1 && \
    docker-php-ext-install amqp
```

Reference: https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/1029#issuecomment-650576137

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM php:7.4.8-fpm-alpine

# Add AMQP extension
RUN apk add \
        --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/main \
        --no-cache \
        rabbitmq-c-dev \
        && pecl install amqp \
        && docker-php-ext-enable amqp

//...
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users also with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody has a legacy app which needs php7.3. use these steps in your dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.3.20-fpm

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update \
   && apt-get install -y \
       librabbitmq-dev \
       curl \
   && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath
```

after that build the legacy php-amqp version v1.9.4, which has support for php-7.3 from source and enable the php extension:

```
RUN curl https://github.com/php-amqp/php-amqp/archive/refs/tags/v1.9.4.tar.gz --location -o /tmp/php-amqp-v1.9.4.tar.gz \
    && mkdir /tmp/php-amqp-v1.9.4 \
    && tar -C /tmp/php-amqp-v1.9.4 -xf /tmp/php-amqp-v1.9.4.tar.gz --strip-components=1 \
    && (cd /tmp/php-amqp-v1.9.4 && phpize && ./configure && make && make install) \
    && rm -rfv /tmp/php-amqp-v1.9.4 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable amqp
```